# Binding to all IPs and producing valid links

Tags: .net, wcf, binding

I've got an app which will be running on multiple servers. It exposes a WCF Endpoint. I'd like the endpoint to be available both using loopback and any other IPs the server has (I don't want to have to configure the IP address of each one, especially since they may potentially change)

The app runs both as windows service and a Console app. I know I can bind to all addresses by using the `http://0.0.0.0/<Blah>/` syntax but the links inside wsdl, etc... reference IP address `0.0.0.0` no matter which IP was used when requesting the pages.

Is there any way I can get WCF to use all IPs and respond correctly to them all?

Comment: This question needs specifics. WCF endpoint URLs can be set in your config files, which would seem to solve your problem, but obviously there's some problem with this; what is it? How is WSDL involved? Are you referring to the config files that are automatically generated for a service reference via WSDL? Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: @PaulKeister, I'm doing `Dim Host As New ServiceHost(GetType(MyService), baseAddress)` `Host.Open`. WSDL is not required (I may use during dev but never want to describe this service publicly). If I were to go down the config route (a pain when supporting console and service), how exactly would I set multiple endpoints for the same service?

Comment: See my answer below. Since you're goal is to deploy in different scenarios, it would seem configuration based endpoints are a good fit, but perhaps I don't understand your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that dynamically binds to all operational IPV4 sockets. Of course you'll still have to keep track of what address and ports you're binding to and report them to whatever service is implementing your GetKnownNodes() function. Note that I'm changing the port to avoid a conflict with the loopback address and the external IP. This could be handled differently, of course.

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Stackoverflow11750995
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITimeService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string TimeAsString();
    }

    public class TimeService : ITimeService
    {
        public string TimeAsString()
        {
            return string.Format("The time is {0:f}", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Stackoverflow11750995.TimeService)))
            {
                int port = 12345;

                foreach (var adpt in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
                {
                    if (adpt.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                    {
                        foreach (var addr in adpt.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                        {
                            if (addr.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                            {
                                string uri = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/Service", addr.Address, port++);
                                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITimeService), new NetTcpBinding(), uri);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example but it doesn't quite address my issue. To clarify, I've got multiple servers running on Amazon EC2. Part of the WCF is a `GetKnownNodes()` which returns endpoints for other servers. This way, any individual node only needs to know one other initially to join and register in a network. Because of all this, I want to make the servers as close to identical as possible (so that if I need more capacity, I can spin up 20, not spin up, configure, spin up, configure, etc...). The only difference between servers is the IP addresses they'll have

Comment: (Cont) as such, I want one URL (say `net.tcp://1.2.3.4/Eeney`) where the `1.2.3.4` is appropriate for the local server - so it's the `localhost` in your example that I want to be dynamic. The added twist of having the core code usually run as a service, but optionally as a console app for debugging/monitoring means that a config-less solution is preferable (most config is stored by "the network" and shared with new, authenticated nodes)

Comment: OK, I think I got it now. See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks Paul, That's the functionality I'm looking for. I have to admit, I was hoping for a more elegant / EF-centric answer as opposed to enumerating NICs. I suspect there's no better way but I'll leave this open for a couple of days in case anyone else has a bright idea